# Node + SQL Server : Get row data as stream

Tags: sql-server, node.js, stream

I try to use [Node.Js connector](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql) with [Microsoft driver](https://github.com/Azure/node-sqlserver) to communicate with a SQL Server. In the connector docs I've found a good option named 'stream'. It add ability to asynchronously obtain row objects.

My data have some specific - some columns have large binary data (> 100 Mb). So even one row may be really large. I'm looking for ability to get each row data as a stream. It is possible in .NET driver ([CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.commandbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration). Is it possible in Node.js?

UPDATED
Here is a code to demonstrate the problem:

Custom writable stream module:

```
var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');

function WritableObjects() {

    stream.Writable.call(
        this,
        {
            objectMode: true
        }
    );

}

util.inherits( WritableObjects, stream.Writable );

WritableObjects.prototype._write = function( chunk, encoding, doneWriting ) {
    console.log('write', chunk, encoding);
    doneWriting();
};


module.exports = {
    WritableObjects: WritableObjects
};
```

and database query code:

```
var sw = new wstream.WritableObjects();
var request = new sql.Request(connection);
request.stream = true;
request.pipe(sw);
request.query('SELECT DataId, Data FROM ds.tData WHERE DataId in (1)');

sw.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Stream err  ', err)
});

sw.on('pipe', function(src) {
    console.log('Stream pipe ')
});

sw.on('finish', function(data) {
    console.log('Stream finish')
});
```

I this example `chunk` parameter of `_write` method contains the whole data of db record, not a stream. Because `Data` field contains a big varbinary data memory of node process also grows huge.

Comment: There is no expectation sql server would ever be able to stream the bytes of a row -- the system does not do that at it's core.  Data is returned by row.  You could write your own module to do this by splitting up the row content if you really need it -- but that would make your application slower not faster.

Comment: .NET data provider is able do that. ExecuteReader method returns SqlDataReader instance, which has Read method to read tne next record and GetBytes method to read a part of binary data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can stream query with the `node-mssql` package as stated here: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql

> stream - Stream recordsets/rows instead of returning them all at once as an argument of callback (default: false). You can also enable streaming for each request independently (request.stream = true). Always set to true if you plan to work with large amount of rows.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this option above. But as I understand it doesn't provide ability to get stream of row. I try example from docs and a row object is passed to 'row' event callback. Not stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mssql-async, an [async/await wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql-async#advanced-usage) of mssql's package, to do what you want:

```
    const stream = db.stream('SELECT name FROM mytable')
    for await (const row of stream) {
      // work on the row
    }
```